# Stylesheet could not be loaded in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2

I am installing magento 2.2 on server. its install completely, but after that home page and admin panel could not loaded css.

[image]

i tried lots of thing, like:

1.`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

2. `

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

```
To:



 Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
```

buts still its not fix. 
the same magento website is work perfectly on localhost, this issue is only on server.

Comment: check .htaccess file is present inside the pub folder

Comment: Please chekc mod rewrite enabled at your server

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan yes , you are correct, i disble the .htaccess file inside the pub, and its start working. before that i am trying only with .htaccess  in root folder and inside static folder. thank you once again

Comment: Always welcome @sam